# Store input after submitting to show it

Tags: javascript

I am doing a rock, paper and scissors exercise and I just added a form with an input text and an input button to store the user name and show it on the DOM.

The thing is, with console.log($userName.value) it will only show me the value when it is on the box, if I delete it or submit it will show nothing or undefined, I added the form.submit() because I want the user to send the text on the input and then let the input empty (I also tried to set the .value to an empty string but it won't work either way.

I added it to a variable with innerHTML to show it on the DOM but if I clear the input it will show undefined.

I am probably skipping a few steps but I don't know how to get to it. Any guidance would be appreciated.

```js
// Global DOM variables
const $selectBtn = document.querySelectorAll("[data-selector]");
const $displayUserScore = document.querySelector("#user-score");
const $displayComputerScore = document.querySelector("#computer-score")
const $showScore = document.querySelector("h5");
const $theWinnerIs = document.querySelector('#result-winner');
const $refreshBtnContainer = document.querySelector('#refresh-button-container');
const $icons = ["", "", "✂️"];
let $userForm = document.querySelector('#user-form');
let $userName = document.querySelector('#user-name');

// Score vaiables
const choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
let userScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;

$userForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    $newUserName = $userName.value;
    $userForm.submit();
})

// For each button of buttons...
$selectBtn.forEach(function(button){
    
    button.addEventListener("click", function() {
        let computerOption = computerRandom() // Store random computer play on var
        const userOption = button.dataset.selector; // userOption is equal to data-selector attribute
        
        // Invoke functions plays the game and shows final winner.
        playGame(userOption, computerOption);
        theWinner();
        
        // Add function with results
        function playGame(userOption, computerOption) {

            if (userOption === "rock") {
                if (computerOption === "scissors") {
                    userScore++;
                    $displayUserScore.innerHTML = userScore;
                    $showScore.innerHTML = "The machine chooses "+"<span class=\"icon\">" + $icons[2] + "</span>" + ", you BEAT him!";
                } else if (computerOption === "paper") {
                    computerScore++;
                    $displayComputerScore.innerHTML = computerScore;
                    $showScore.innerHTML = "The machine chooses "+"<span class=\"icon\">" + $icons[1] + "</span>" + ", you LOSE!";
                } else if (userOption === computerOption) {
                    $showScore.innerHTML = "Draw!";
                }
            }

            if (userOption === "paper") {
                if (computerOption === "rock") {
                    userScore++;
                    $displayUserScore.innerHTML = userScore;
                    $showScore.innerHTML = "The machine chooses "+"<span class=\"icon\">" + $icons[0] + "</span>" + ", you BEAT him!";
                } else if (computerOption === "scissors") {
                    computerScore++;
                    $displayComputerScore.innerHTML = computerScore;
                    $showScore.innerHTML = "The machine chooses "+"<span class=\"icon\">" + $icons[2] + "</span>" + ", you LOSE!";
                } else if (userOption === computerOption) {
                    $showScore.innerHTML = "Draw!";
                }
            }

            if (userOption === "scissors") {
                if (computerOption === "paper") {
                    userScore++;
                    $displayUserScore.innerHTML = userScore;
                    $showScore.innerHTML = "The machine chooses "+"<span class=\"icon\">" + $icons[1] + "</span>" + ", you BEAT him!";
                } else if (computerOption === "rock") {
                    computerScore++;
                    $displayComputerScore.innerHTML = computerScore;
                    $showScore.innerHTML = "The machine chooses "+"<span class=\"icon\">" + $icons[0] + "</span>" + ", you LOSE!";
                } else if (userOption === computerOption) {
                    $showScore.innerHTML = "Draw!";
                }
            }

        }
        
        // Add a winners text function
        function theWinner() {
            if (userScore === 5) {
                $theWinnerIs.innerHTML = $userName.value;
            } else if (computerScore === 5) {
                $theWinnerIs.innerHTML = "The machine!";
            }
        }

        if (userScore === 5 || computerScore === 5) {
            const $refreshBtn = document.createElement('button');
            $refreshBtn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Play again!"));
            $refreshBtn.className = "refresh-btn";
            $refreshBtnContainer.appendChild($refreshBtn);
            let len = $selectBtn.length;

            for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                $selectBtn[i].disabled = true;
            }
            
                $refreshBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
                userScore = 0;
                computerScore = 0;
                $displayUserScore.innerHTML = userScore;
                $displayComputerScore.innerHTML = computerScore;
                $showScore.innerHTML = "";
                $theWinnerIs.innerHTML = "";
                $refreshBtnContainer.innerHTML= "";
                for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    $selectBtn[i].disabled = false;
                }
            })   
        }

    })
    
})

// Random computer choice
function computerRandom () {
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length);
    return choices[randomNumber];
}
```

```css
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 5%;
}

h2 {
    color:rebeccapurple;
    font-size: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    font-style: italic;
}

#user-name {
    margin-bottom: 4em;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: .6em;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}

#submit-name {
    padding: .6em;
    margin-left: .5em;
    background: rebeccapurple;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}

.btn-selector {
    font-size: 4em;
    background: rebeccapurple;
    margin: .1em;
    padding: .2em;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 20%;
    transition: 150ms;
}
.btn-selector:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
}

#results {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.score {
    margin-right: 1em;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-style: italic;
}

h3 {
    color: rebeccapurple;
    font-style: italic;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

h5 {
    margin-top: 7px;
    color: olive;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.icon {
    font-size: 3em;
}

.refresh-btn {
    padding: .8em;
    background: rebeccapurple;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-style: bold;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Rock, paper and scissors</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h2>What is your name?</h2>
        <form id ="user-form">
            <input type="text" id="user-name" placeholder="Please, insert your name..">
            <input type="submit" id="submit-name" value="Enviar">
        </form>
        <button class="btn-selector" data-selector="rock"></button>
        <button class="btn-selector" data-selector="paper"></button>
        <button class="btn-selector" data-selector="scissors">✂️</button>
        <div id="results">
        <h4>You: <span id="user-score" class="score" data-user-score>0</span></h4>
        <h4>Computer: <span id="computer-score" class="score" data-computer-score>0</span></h4>
    </div>
    <h5></h5>
        <div>
            <h3>And the winner is...</h3>
            <h3 id="result-winner"></h3>
        </div>
        <div id="refresh-button-container">    
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You already used `.value` when setting `$userName`. You don't need it again when calling `console.log()`. Just use `console.log($userName)`.

Comment: Notice that you have two variables named `$userName`. The first one is the element, the second one is its value. Avoid doing that, it causes confusion. You don't need the local variable with the same name.

Comment: Quick question, do your form will be sended to a server ?

Comment: @Barmar Jesuschrist, you right, I declared it two times, but console.log the variable itself will throw me the whole html input and I just wanted to show the value, right?

Comment: @horhorou No, it won't be, maybe is that the problem? what other alternatives do I have?

Comment: It won't show the whole html input after `const $userName = document.querySelector('#user-name').value;`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a different variable in the function. There you can use the `$userName` global variable to access the HTML element, and `.value` to get its value.

```js
let $userForm = document.querySelector('#user-form');
let $userName = document.querySelector('#user-name');

$userForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  const name = $userName.value;
  console.log(name);
  $userForm.submit();
})
```

```html
<form id="user-form">
  <input type="text" id="user-name" placeholder="Please, insert your name..">
  <input type="submit" id="submit-name" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation and sorry for the confusion on variables, I have test your code but it doesn't work, can't access the local variable because I am accessing to it from outside the scope, I have edited my main post with the whole code so it will be easy to understand me.

Comment: `$userForm.submit()` will submit the form and reload the page. Setting variables outside the function will have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if your form will be sent, at least I don't think so.

If you want to display the name of the user or even store this data somewhere to display it somewhere you can do it this way

***HTML code***

```
<form id ="user-form">
  <input type="text" id="user-name" placeholder="Please, insert your name.." onchange="registerInput(this);">
  <input type="submit" id="submit-name" value="Enviar">
</form>
<h1>
</h1>
```

---

***JavaScript code***

```
// Here we initialize a global variable
var playerUsername = ""

let $userForm = document.querySelector('#user-form');
let $userName = document.querySelector('#user-name');


function registerInput(e)
{
    const value = e.value;
    // We assign the value of the input to playerUsername
    // So we can access it globally
    playerUsername = value;
}

$userForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        // Here we show the user
        document.querySelector('h1').innerText = 'Hello : ' + inputValue;
        
        // Now let's remove the value of the input
        // We put an empty string 
        $userName.innerValue = ""

        // Well done !

})
```

*Link :
https://jsfiddle.net/k49bgu0c/6/*

> In case you change the .html page you will lose access to this variable, so how to do in this case?

> For that you can store the result of your input in the [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), this one will allow you to access to the data you have inserted inside, I let you read about the localStorage and how it works

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, I don't completely understand your code (I am still learning) but anyway when you type and submit the input won't clear and that is my point, I want to clear it and keep the value stored, so I think I should look into localStorage?

Comment: No problem, let me just make it more simple for you
And I'll explain with my edit

Comment: yeah, that would be nice, but I tried to implement your code and didn't work (I edited my main post with the whole code) is it a scope problem, maybe?

Comment: Ok I did understand it now... thanks, so I guess I can move the onchange event from the html doc. to the .js doc, right?

Answer (score 0):

### Submit Event

There are few things you should be aware of when you have a `<form>` and you register it to the "submit" event.

- Default behavior of a `<form>` is to gather all values of all form controls that are:

  - within the `<form>` itself
  - OR is associated with the `<form>` via the `form` attribute.
  - AND has a `name` attribute with a valid value. (excluding buttons)
- Once data is collected, sent to the server, it will expect a response from the server. If there is no server, it will return a blank page (not good UX).
- The "submit" event is "organically" triggered two ways.

  - The user uses the <kbd>Return/Enter</kbd> key when focused on an `<input>`
  - The user clicks a submit button. The following is what constitutes a submit button:

    - **Figure I** (Within `<form id="X">`)

      ```html
      <button>OK</button>
      <button type='submit'>OK</button>
      <input type='submit'>
      <input type='image' src='https://loremflickr.com/48/24'>
      ```
    - **Figure II** (Outside of `<form id="X">`)

      ```html
      <button form="X">OK</button>
      <button type='submit' form="X">OK</button>
      <input type='submit' form="X">
      <input type='image' src='https://loremflickr.com/48/24' form="X">
      ```

Not using a server, I assume that the behavior previously mentioned is undesirable. If so, [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) is needed (see **Example A**)

### [Closure](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-closure/#:%7E:text=In%20JavaScript%2C%20a%20closure%20is,the%20lexical%20scoping%20works%20first)

Define or declare a variable ***outside*** of the function, but within scope. Within scope in this context would just require that the variable be in the "vicinity" of the function to keep things simple see **Figure III**.

**Figure III**

```js
let playerName = '';
function eventHandler(event) {//...
```

### Example A

```js
let playerName = '';

function eventHandler(event) {
  // Stop the form from sending to a server
  event.preventDefault();
  // Reference all form controls
  const IO = this.elements;
  // Assign value to variable outside of function
  playerName = IO.username.value;
  // Clear input
  IO.username.value = '';
  console.log(playerName);
}

document.forms.rps.onsubmit = eventHandler;
```

```html
<form id='rps'>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Enter Name</legend>
    <input id='username' name='username'><button>OK</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

The function and everything within the function gets garbage collected, but because you've created a closure by assigning a value from inside a function to a variable outside of the function, that value still resides within the variable after the function terminates. To verify, enter something and submit it. There should be a log entered in the console with the value of whatever you entered. That's during the run of the function, so to really be sure, right-click on the snippet directly and click "inspect", and click the "console" tab. Enter: `console.log(playerName)` in the console. (See **Appendix** on Dev Tools)

### Hidden `<input>`

Another way to save values is by using a hidden `<input>`. The saved value will persist until the page is unloaded or the `<input>`'s value is reassigned. (see **Example B**). There are many ways to hide an `<input>` and there basically 2 types of hidden:

- **Visibly Hidden `<input>`**

  - Users will not see the `<input>`, but as far as the browser and the DOM is concerned nothing special about said `<input>`. It takes up space and it is within the layout.
  - Typically, CSS properties such as `opacity` and `visibility` hide tags this way. Some hacky ways include, `color` and `background` having the same color value or setting lengths to 0 like `width`, `height`, `font-size`, etc. HTML attributes `hidden` and attribute/value `type="hidden"` are slightly different in that the latter will be included in a collection during a "submit" event.
- **`display: none`**

  - Users will not see the `<input>`, nor does it occupy space in the layout. The DOM and browser still "sees" it and access it by normal means. If the `<input>` was made visible by `display:`*"AnythingButNone"* it would pop into existence amid other tags and probably cause unsightly shifting. So this form of hiding is best used for tags you don't plan on making visible.

Since the only reason to use a hidden `<input>` is to store a value `display: none` will be the best choice. (see **Example B**).

### Example B

```js
function eventHandler(event) {
  // Stop the form from sending to a server
  event.preventDefault();
  // Reference all form controls
  const IO = this.elements;
  // Assign the value of #username to #player
  IO.player.value = IO.username.value;
  // Clear input
  IO.username.value = '';
  console.log(IO.player.value);
}

document.forms.rps.onsubmit = eventHandler;
```

```html
<form id='rps'>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Enter Name</legend>
    <input id='username' name='username'><button>OK</button>
  </fieldset>
  <input id='player' style='display: none'>
</form>
```

### Appendix

**DevTools**

[Firefox Developer Tools](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/index.html)

[Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/)

[Edge DevTools](https://learn.microsoft.com/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide)